# i am unable to set classpath

Tags: java

When I try to add classpath using `export CLASSPATH=/location`, it updates the CLASSPATH temporarily.

When I look at the classpath using echo `$CLASSPATH`, I can see that the changes are updated in classpath, but when I close and reopen the terminal, I can not see the update which I did.

[image: empty classpath]

Tell me how to add a classpath permanently.

Comment: What classpath are we talking here?

Answer (score 0):

The `export CLASSPATH=/location` command will work only for the current terminal session. To make the changes permanent add the line

`export CLASSPATH=/location`

to `~/.bashrc` or `~/.profile`